# How SpringBoot dependency injection works with different type of annotations

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans

I recently started exploring `Spring Boot`. I see that there are 2 ways to define `Beans` in `Spring Boot`.

1. Define `@Bean` in the class annotated with `@SprinBootApplication`
2. Define `@Bean` in a class annotated with `@Configuration`

I am also confused about `stereo-type annotation` `@Repository`  `@Service` `@Controller` etc.

Can someone please explain how dependency-injection works with these annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Either you use @Bean in any of your @Configuration or @SpringBootApplication class or mark the bean classes explicitly with annotations like @Service, @Component @Repository etc.

**@Service or @Component**

When you mark a class with @Service or @Compoenent and if spring's annotation scanning scope allows it to reach to the package, spring will register the instances of those classes as `spring beans`. 
You can provide the packages to be included/excluded during scan with `@ComponentScan`

---

**@Bean**

`@Beans` are marked on factory methods which can create an instance of a particular class.

```
@Bean 
public Account getAccount(){
  return new DailyAccount();
}
```

Now in you application you can simply @Autowire Account and spring will internally call its factory method `getAccount`, which in turn returns an instance of `DailyAccount`.

There is a simple difference of using @Bean vs @Service or @Compoenent. 
The first one makes your beans loosely coupled to each other.

- In the @Bean, you have flexibility to change the account implementation without even changing any of the account classes.
- Consider if your classes instantiation is a multi-step operation like read properties values etc then you can easily do it in your @Bean method.
- @Bean also helps if you don't have source code access to the class you are trying to instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot auto-configuration attempts to automatically configure your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have added.

You need to opt-in to auto-configuration by adding the **@EnableAutoConfiguration** or **@SpringBootApplication** annotations to one of your **@Configuration** classes.

You are free to use any of the standard Spring Framework techniques to define your beans and their injected dependencies. For simplicity, we often find that using **@ComponentScan** (to find your beans) and using **@Autowired** (to do constructor injection) works well.

Answer (score 2):

> One way is to define @Bean in the class annotated with
>   @SprinBootApplication

If you see `@SprinBootApplication` it is combination of many annotation, and one of them is `@Configuration`. So when you define `@Bean` in the Main class, it means it's inside `@Configuration` class.

According to [Configuration docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) :

> Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be
>   processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and
>   service requests for those beans at runtime.

---

> class annotated with @Configuration

When you define `@Bean` is a class annotated with  `@Configuration` class, it means it is the part of spring configuration all the `Beans` define in it all available for `Dependency-Injection`.

> I have also seen some code where neither of the 2 above approaches
>   have been used and yet dependency injection works fine. I have tried
>   to research a lot on this but could not find any concrete answer to
>   this. Is this possible?

I am assuming you are talking about [Sterio-type annotation](https://www.dineshonjava.com/stereotype-annotations-in-spring/). Every sterio type annotation has [@Component](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), according to docs :

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are
>   considered as candidates for auto-detection when using
>   annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.